# Codeigniter large video is uploading fine but audio is not uploading

Tags: php, codeigniter, audio, file-upload

In my controller I am trying to add audio and video, I changed my php.ini file and extended max_file_size, post_size etc.

When I upload a video of **25M**, it is successfully getting upload

but when I try to upload an audio file of **4MB** then it got failed.

Then again I tried to upload an audio file of **433KB**, it got successfully upload.

HERE is my code below and I am not able to find what is the reason its not working

```
     if(!empty($_FILES['audio_upload']['name'])){
            $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'mp3|wmv|mp4';
            $config['max_size'] = '0';
            $config['file_name'] = $this->input->post('sub_category_name');

            //Load upload library and initialize configuration
            $this->load->library('upload',$config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);


            if($this->upload->do_upload('audio_upload')){
                $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
                $audio_upload = $uploadData['file_name'];
            }
            else{
                $audio_upload = '';
            }
        }
        if( !empty($audio_upload)){
            $media_link = 'uploads/'.$audio_upload;
        }
        else{
            $media_link = $this->input->post('media_link');
        }
    //**************************************END
    //**************************************Video Upload
        if(!empty($_FILES['video_upload']['name'])){
            $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'mp3|wmv|mp4';
            $config['max_size'] = '0';
            $config['file_name'] = $this->input->post('sub_category_name');

            //Load upload library and initialize configuration
            $this->load->library('upload',$config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if($this->upload->do_upload('video_upload')){
                $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
                $video_upload = $uploadData['file_name'];
            }
            else{
                $video_upload = '';
            }
        }
        if( !empty($video_upload)){
            $video_link = 'uploads/'.$video_upload;
        }
        else{
            $video_link = $this->input->post('media_link');
        }
```

Comment: any error messages ??

Comment: Unfortunately no error messages

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: check apache error logs then and check both mp3 ext is same

Comment: logs contain no error, both are mp3 files

Comment: Have you checked the output of `$this->upload->display_errors()` ? Does `$this->upload->do_upload('audio_upload')` return true or false?

Comment: its returning false

Comment: `if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('audio_upload') ) var_dump($this->upload->display_errors()); exit;`